How to compute byte size of list<T> in C#
I want to send a large list of objects to another web service for intake. The web service has a byte limit of 6Mb. I want to send my list of 7,000+ objects in 5Mb "batches."
To do this, I need to compute the byte size of the objects and send a batch when the total bytes reaches 5Mb. The issue is that each object can have multiple child objects, and each child objects can have multiple child objects too.
The batch of objects is first serialized to Json before being sent in the body of the request.
Is there a way of computing the byte size of each object at runtime and then adding the value to a running total?
The code snippet below shows what I have to send the list:
jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, 0);
request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Content = new StringContent(jsonList , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
response = await client.SendAsync(request);
jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            


Do the objects' sizes vary a lot?

It looks like you're not really interested in any sort of in-memory size - only the serialized size. The way to find that out is to serialize it.

Assuming all your parent Items are less than 5Mb, I would serialize one parent at this to the batch when there is still space. Start a new batch when json lenght of parent is bigger than available batch space.

While an int has 4 bytes memory size, serialized as JSON it might look like this: "field_name": 1234567890,\n (27 bytes as utf8) plus braces, etc. So, it is really hard to tell. Make experiments to find out a sensible batch size.

The easiest method is to just guesstimate a small enough quantity and use Linq's Chunk operator.
If that is not accurate enough then you can run a loop in an iterator function, yielding a MemoryStream of enough items to just fill the stream to the size you want, then starting another stream.
public static IEnumerable<Stream>(IEnumerable<YourClass> source, long maxLength)
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();  // add settings?
    using var enumer = source.GetEnumerator();
    var (ms, writer) = GetNewStream();
    while (enumer.MoveNext());
    {
        var currentPos = ms.Position;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, enumer.Current);
        if (ms.Position >= maxLength)
        {
            writer.Close();
            ms.SetLength(currentPos);  // truncate to old position
            ms.Write((byte)']');
            ms.Position = 0;  // reset ready for eading
            yield return ms;
            (ms, writer) = GetNewStream();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, enumer.Current);
        }
    }

    if (ms.Length != 1)  // was not empty list
    {
        writer.Close();
        ms.Write((byte)']');
        ms.Position = 0;  // reset ready for eading
        yield return ms;
    }
}

private static (MemoryStream, StreamWriter) GetNewStream()
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write((byte)'[');
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms, leaveOpen: true)
    return (ms, writer);
}


Nice one. I considered MemoryStream too as an obviuous solution but was too lazy to type it out :-)

Minor nitpick: This stops at 5000, the question mentioned 5 MB. Also I think you swallow the Current object between blocks. You cut off after the previous object and don't add the Current to the new stream before calling MoveNext()

You're quite right, fixed some bugs.

This is good stuff, Thank You.

Start a StringBuilder with "[", serialize the list objects in a loop one by one and keep adding to the builder (don't forget the commas between objects).
Shortly before reaching the limit, close with "]", convert to UTF8 bytes, fire the request, then reset the builder with a new "[".
As long as your content is mainly in the ASCII-Range, the builder.Length should be equal or only slightly less than the byte length of the content.
If you have lots of special characters, UTF-8 needs to represent them with multiple bytes so your content bytes will grow faster than the string length. In that case, you need to convert each json string to UTF8 and measure that byte count to keep track of the byte total.
Leave yourself some kb leeway before the limit to account for headers and stuff and you should be good.

I was going to suggest the same thing, except that one could use StreamContent instead, using Encoding.UTF8 to write the objects to a MemoryStream instance, so you'd have accurate knowledge of the length. Of course you could also implement your own HttpContent altogether that does not copy more than the limit.
